# Errors when Compiling Nginx with Pagespeed on CentOS 7

Tags: centos, nginx, make, mod-pagespeed

I am trying to compile Nginx with Pagespeed from source and I am having a hard time trying to resolve the `not found` errors I am seeing when I add the configure settings. This is my configure settings:

I am using CentOS 7 - 64 bit

**Configure Settings:**

```
sudo ./configure --add-module=/nginx-compile/modules/ngx_pagespeed-release-1.9.32.1-beta \
--prefix=/etc/nginx \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid \
--lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp \
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp \
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp \
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-http_addition_module \
--with-http_sub_module \
--with-http_dav_module \
--with-http_flv_module \
--with-http_mp4_module \
--with-http_gunzip_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_random_index_module \
--with-http_secure_link_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--with-mail \
--with-mail_ssl_module \
--with-file-aio \
--with-ipv6 \
--with-http_spdy_module \
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector \ 
--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
--user=nginx \
--group=nginx
```

When I add the above in ssh, I am getting the following `not found` errors and `no supported file AIO was found` error. Here is the list I get:

**Errors after executing Configure:**

```
checking for OS
 + Linux 3.10.0-123.el7.x86_64 x86_64
checking for C compiler ... found
 + using GNU C compiler
 + gcc version: 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16) (GCC)
checking for gcc -pipe switch ... found
checking for gcc builtin atomic operations ... not found
checking for C99 variadic macros ... not found
checking for gcc variadic macros ... not found
checking for unistd.h ... found
checking for inttypes.h ... found
checking for limits.h ... found
checking for sys/filio.h ... not found
checking for sys/param.h ... found
checking for sys/mount.h ... found
checking for sys/statvfs.h ... found
checking for crypt.h ... found
checking for Linux specific features
checking for epoll ... not found
checking for O_PATH ... not found
checking for sendfile() ... not found
checking for sendfile64() ... not found
checking for sys/prctl.h ... found
checking for prctl(PR_SET_DUMPABLE) ... not found
checking for sched_setaffinity() ... not found
checking for crypt_r() ... not found
checking for sys/vfs.h ... found
checking for poll() ... not found
checking for /dev/poll ... not found
checking for kqueue ... not found
checking for crypt() ... not found
checking for crypt() in libcrypt ... not found
checking for F_READAHEAD ... not found
checking for posix_fadvise() ... not found
checking for O_DIRECT ... not found
checking for F_NOCACHE ... not found
checking for directio() ... not found
checking for statfs() ... not found
checking for statvfs() ... not found
checking for dlopen() ... not found
checking for dlopen() in libdl ... not found
checking for sched_yield() ... not found
checking for sched_yield() in librt ... not found
checking for SO_SETFIB ... not found
checking for SO_ACCEPTFILTER ... not found
checking for TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT ... not found
checking for TCP_KEEPIDLE ... not found
checking for TCP_FASTOPEN ... not found
checking for TCP_INFO ... not found
checking for accept4() ... not found
checking for kqueue AIO support ... not found
checking for Linux AIO support ... not found

./configure: no supported file AIO was found
Currently file AIO is supported on FreeBSD 4.3+ and Linux 2.6.22+ only
```

I also installed the following dependencies before I added the configure settings:

```
sudo yum install gcc gcc-c++ pcre-devel zlib-devel make unzip openssl-devel
```

The configuration I used is similar to the configuration settings that comes when I install Nginx using centos inbuilt repo except it has the pagespeed module added.

---

**UPDATE:**

The actual problem was the way I've split the line when passing the `--params` to the configure call which is incorrect and was causing the errors. Thanks to [@XavierLucas answer](https://serverfault.com/a/636642/247421) below, the error was resolved once I added `--with-cc-opt` and `--params` in 1 line.

**EXTENDING:**

While the above was the cause for error, I also learnt that its good to have the following libraries installed too in order for Nginx to make the most out of its core features and while having pagespeed module installed:

```
gcc 
gcc-c++ 
pcre-devel 
zlib-devel 
make 
unzip 
openssl-devel 
libaio-devel
glibc 
glibc-devel 
glibc-headers
libevent
linux-vdso.so.1
libpthread.so.0
libcrypt.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
librt.so.1
libm.so.6
libpcre.so.0
libssl.so.10
libcrypto.so.10
libdl.so.2
libz.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libfreebl3.so
libgssapi_krb5.so.2
libkrb5.so.3
libcom_err.so.2
libk5crypto.so.3
libkrb5support.so.0
libkeyutils.so.1
libresolv.so.2
libselinux.so.1
```

And

```
yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'
```

Comment: Since CentOS 7 should have a 3.10+ kernel, try installing libaio-devel to provide the headers needed for AIO.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @cyberx86 I installed libaio-devel now by typing `sudo yum install libaio-devel`. After that when I added the above configure again, I am getting the same errors.

Comment: Another thing I noticed is I dont see the `no supported file AIO was found` error if I dont include the `--with-cc-opt` and `--param` options. Are they related?

Comment: a) Do you have libaio installed (in addition to libaio-devel) b) can you actually compile Nginx without the --add-module parameter you listed (if you can't - then the error is unrelated to pagespeed). c) Try to install the Development Tools group if you can't compile Nginx without pagespeed (yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'); The cc-opt and param specify optimizations and preprocessor directives - there might be some overlap in the function (tuning/optimization)

Comment: thanks again @cyberx86 I did these and the error is still showing (a) Checked is libaio is installed using `yum info libaio` and it shows that it is installed. (b) I removed the pagespeed module (--add-module parameter) from the configure and the error was still showing. So I guess this confirms its not related to pagespeed. (c) I installed the Development Tools using `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'` and tried again (without PS module) and the errors are still the same. :( If I want to check if the cc-opt and param has any overlapping functions, how can I check this?

Comment: I removed the `--with-file-aio` parameter and I am now seeing this error: `checking for int size ...cc: error:  : No such file or directory
cc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.

./configure: error: can not detect int size
cat: objs/autotest.c: No such file or directory`

Comment: When I remove `--cc` and `--param` parameters, it seems to work fine. Do I need to even add those? What are the effects if I compile without those? The only reason I have that long list of configure parameters is because I have it matching the parameters that came with default nginx installation from centos repo. If possible would you be able to give me a list of compile parameters that would be ideal for a web server that will be running Joomla and phpbb please? So this way I dont need to add the ones I dont understand.

Comment: Nginx is C not C++ you don't need gcc-c++

Comment: Hi @XavierLucas But I got that from google pagespeed docs where it says `gcc-c++` dependency needs to be installed for pagespeed module: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

Comment: @blackops_programmer Oh yeah pagespeed is c++, my bad. Check BUILD/nginx-{version}/objs/autoconf.err log. Looks like you are missing gcc and libgcc. And don't remove AIO support it's very important (Asynchronous IO).

Comment: Good idea @XavierLucas I just compiled it using the configure parameters in my original post and had a look at the autoconf.err. I am seeing this, could this be related to my problem? `checking for Linux AIO support

cc: error: ssp-buffer-size=4: No such file or directory
`

Comment: the `cc: error: ssp-buffer-size=4: No such file or directory` error is showing pretty much for everything like after checking AIO support, accept4(), TCP_INFO, etc.. That is probably what is maybe causing the not found error and other issue perhaps?

Comment: @blackops_programmer Hum the `missing poll` is an indicator I think. This means you are missing `glibc glibc-devel glibc-headers`.

Comment: I tried `yum install glibc glibc-devel glibc-headers` but it appears to be there already. Its saying "Nothing to do".

Comment: I'm really confused. I don't see how it's possible for poll not to be found as it's defined by this library. Are you sure you din't mix archs when installing dependencies ? Could you post `rpm -qa` result somewhere ?

Comment: Hi @XavierLucas I really appreciate you for patiently trying to help me out. I have updated my Original post with the `rpm -qa` result. I am thinking if I should maybe start over in a fresh server and carefully redo all the steps again and see.

Comment: I just tried it again on a brand new server with centos 7 installed and I am getting the same error.

Comment: I can give you my server access if it helps

Comment: Can you tell me what location does `with-cc-opt` look in? I have downloaded the custom build in `/nginx-compile/modules` directory that is placed in `~` and not inside `~/opt/` directory. Could it the reason for not found errors when I add `--cc` parameters?

Comment: is it okay to compile without `--with-cc-opt` and `--param` parameters? Will it affect anything if I dont include these 2 parameters?

Comment: @blackops_programmer First thing I see is that your installed package list is missing `libevent` and `coreutils-libs`.

Comment: Please remember that **comments are temporary** and may go away at any time. Anything necessary to understanding the question should be edited into the question itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To stop a bit the looong chat going on, here's the C/C++ libraries you need for a compiled version of nginx with pagespeed on CentOS:

```
linux-vdso.so.1
libpthread.so.0
libcrypt.so.1
libstdc++.so.6
librt.so.1
libm.so.6
libpcre.so.0
libssl.so.10
libcrypto.so.10
libdl.so.2
libz.so.1
libgcc_s.so.1
libc.so.6
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
libfreebl3.so
libgssapi_krb5.so.2
libkrb5.so.3
libcom_err.so.2
libk5crypto.so.3
libkrb5support.so.0
libkeyutils.so.1
libresolv.so.2
libselinux.so.1
```

Check with `yum whatprovides <library>` in which package it is available and make sure you have all installed.

**Edit** : Your options are important. For example ssp will limit stackoverflow attacks and has a security purpose. The other options will optimize the binary so it works best for your target arch.

After taking a step back, it seemed weird to me that it would crash on an external library by changing these options. Anyway that's good that you followed the previous steps we discussed so you have the required librairies to get the best performance out of nginx (remember, it's event driven so libevent is a must have !).

**Your actual problem comes from the way you pass `--params` to the configure call**. You are trying to split on a new line inside the string itself.

```
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector \ 
--param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
```

Should be :

```
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic' \
```

And then be prepared for the wall of text :)

Comment: Thanks again Xavier. I am really obliged with your hard working effort on this. I went through the list one by one and the following libraries werent installed before and I've installed them: `libpthread.so.0`, `libstdc++.so.6`, `libssl.so.10`. However the problem is still there only when I use `--with-cc-opt and --param parameters`.

Comment: I am thinking if I should perhaps change the OS since I heard that with debian it is possible to install a precompiled version from repo: http://www.dotdeb.org/   I dont want to give up just yet though. Can you tell me what effect does it have if I dont include the -with-cc-opt and --param parameters please? Since I am able to install if I dont include these 2 parameters. Also a lot of tutorials I've read doesnt mention about these 2 parameters for configure. So I am thinking, do I need it? What purpose does it serve>

Comment: @blackops_programmer Check updated answer, the issue is with your configure call.

Comment: you got it spot on. I did split the `--params` and `--with-cc-opt` into 2 lines. That was it and you are right. Once I added it in 1 line like you showed it worked fine. I am so relived. See sometimes a small line break can cause a lot of worries. Thank you so much for not giving up and helping me out here. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Its good to know that it is useful to have the additional libraries you had suggested. I didint know that. Also pretty much all the tutorials and docs I've read on this had the bare minimum lib for nginx and pagespeed. I've taken a note and listed these libraries so I can install on my production server especially the `libaio-devel`. With maintenance of these libs, they all will be automatically updated during `yum update` right? That should be enough?

Comment: @blackops_programmer Yep if you regularly update your system with `yum update` they'll get updated too. Nginx chooses at compilation time what will be its way to get the best out of what is installed on the system. But if key libraries are missing then unfortunately core parts of the nginx model could be unused. That's why it's so important to have it.

Comment: I've updated my question with the list of libraries that I ended up installing during the steps we went through in comments and with your answer. Can you have a look and let me know if there is anything else that might be useful to install to make the most of nginx + pagespeed?

Comment: @blackops_programmer That's the right ones. We should terminate on this because the topic will be hard to read for our (potential) future readers :)

Answer (score 1):

**This is how to compile nginx 1.10.2 with pagespeed 1.11.33.4 in CentOS 7**

```
yum update
yum install wget curl gcc-c++ pcre-devel zlib-devel make unzip openssl-devel

mkdir /root/custom-nginx
cd /root/custom-nginx

NGINX_VERSION=1.10.2          ### copy and paste, place your nginx version you want to install

wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz

tar zxvf nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}.tar.gz

ls -la ### check downloaded version

cd /root/custom-nginx/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/src/http/modules/
```

#### https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

go to this page in order to find the latest version

-beta does not mean not stable version, 1.11.33.4 is stable version

```
NPS_VERSION=1.11.33.4        ### copy and paste, place your pagespeed version you want to install

wget https://github.com/pagespeed/ngx_pagespeed/archive/release-${NPS_VERSION}-beta.zip -O release-${NPS_VERSION}-beta.zip

unzip release-${NPS_VERSION}-beta.zip

mv ngx_pagespeed-release-${NPS_VERSION}-beta ngx_pagespeed
cd ngx_pagespeed

wget https://dl.google.com/dl/page-speed/psol/${NPS_VERSION}.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ${NPS_VERSION}.tar.gz

cd /root/custom-nginx/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/
```

common configuration (nginx installed from repo + pagespeed)

```
./configure --add-module=/root/custom-nginx/nginx-${NGINX_VERSION}/src/http/modules/ngx_pagespeed --prefix=/etc/nginx --sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx --modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/run/nginx.lock --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/client_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/proxy_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/cache/nginx/scgi_temp --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-ipv6 --with-http_addition_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_mp4_module --with-http_random_index_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_v2_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic'


make && make install
```

Then

```
nano /etc/init.d/nginx
```

Make file and paste the code:

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# nginx - this script starts and stops the nginx daemon
#
# chkconfig:   - 85 15
# description:  NGINX is an HTTP(S) server, HTTP(S) reverse \
#               proxy and IMAP/POP3 proxy server
# processname: nginx
# config:      /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
# config:      /etc/sysconfig/nginx
# pidfile:     /var/run/nginx.pid

# Source function library.
. /etc/rc.d/init.d/functions

# Source networking configuration.
. /etc/sysconfig/network

# Check that networking is up.
[ "$NETWORKING" = "no" ] && exit 0

nginx="/usr/sbin/nginx"
prog=$(basename $nginx)

NGINX_CONF_FILE="/etc/nginx/nginx.conf"

[ -f /etc/sysconfig/nginx ] && . /etc/sysconfig/nginx

lockfile=/var/lock/subsys/nginx

make_dirs() {
   # make required directories
   user=`$nginx -V 2>&1 | grep "configure arguments:.*--user=" | sed 's/[^*]*--user=\([^ ]*\).*/\1/g' -`
   if [ -n "$user" ]; then
      if [ -z "`grep $user /etc/passwd`" ]; then
         useradd -M -s /bin/nologin $user
      fi
      options=`$nginx -V 2>&1 | grep 'configure arguments:'`
      for opt in $options; do
          if [ `echo $opt | grep '.*-temp-path'` ]; then
              value=`echo $opt | cut -d "=" -f 2`
              if [ ! -d "$value" ]; then
                  # echo "creating" $value
                  mkdir -p $value && chown -R $user $value
              fi
          fi
       done
    fi
}

start() {
    [ -x $nginx ] || exit 5
    [ -f $NGINX_CONF_FILE ] || exit 6
    make_dirs
    echo -n $"Starting $prog: "
    daemon $nginx -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && touch $lockfile
    return $retval
}

stop() {
    echo -n $"Stopping $prog: "
    killproc $prog -QUIT
    retval=$?
    echo
    [ $retval -eq 0 ] && rm -f $lockfile
    return $retval
}

restart() {
    configtest || return $?
    stop
    sleep 1
    start
}

reload() {
    configtest || return $?
    echo -n $"Reloading $prog: "
    killproc $nginx -HUP
    RETVAL=$?
    echo
}

force_reload() {
    restart
}

configtest() {
  $nginx -t -c $NGINX_CONF_FILE
}

rh_status() {
    status $prog
}

rh_status_q() {
    rh_status >/dev/null 2>&1
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        rh_status_q && exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    stop)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
        $1
        ;;
    restart|configtest)
        $1
        ;;
    reload)
        rh_status_q || exit 7
        $1
        ;;
    force-reload)
        force_reload
        ;;
    status)
        rh_status
        ;;
    condrestart|try-restart)
        rh_status_q || exit 0
            ;;
    *)
        echo $"Usage: $0 {start|stop|status|restart|condrestart|try-restart|reload|force-reload|configtest}"
        exit 2
esac
```

Check that  /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache  folder is created by nginx

edit  /etc/nginx/your-domain.conf  ### and place your settings

```
###PAGESPEED###
pagespeed on;
pagespeed FileCachePath /var/ngx_pagespeed_cache;
##EXTRA FILTERS
#--> JAVASCRIPT
pagespeed EnableFilters canonicalize_javascript_libraries,rewrite_javascript,combine_javascript,inline_javascript,make_google_analytics_async ;
#--> CSS
pagespeed EnableFilters move_css_above_scripts,move_css_to_head,rewrite_style_attributes,inline_css,inline_google_font_css ;
#--> IMAGES
pagespeed EnableFilters convert_to_webp_lossless,sprite_images,resize_mobile_images,inline_preview_images ;
#--> HTML
pagespeed EnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments,extend_cache ;
#
##EXTRA MODS
pagespeed LazyloadImagesAfterOnload off ;
pagespeed UseExperimentalJsMinifier on ;
pagespeed LowercaseHtmlNames on ;
pagespeed PreserveUrlRelativity on ;
pagespeed XHeaderValue "Modified By dimitrios" ;
#pagespeed ForceCaching on ;
###PAGESPEED###
```

Test cofiguration

```
/usr/sbin/nginx -V  ### must include pagespeed
/usr/sbin/nginx -t  ### syntax must be ok
```

Warning! Disable your repo to prevent nginx update!

Answer (score 0):

Try this to install our basic dependencies, run:

RedHat, CentOS, or Fedora

sudo yum install gcc-c++ pcre-devel zlib-devel make unzip libuuid-devel

Ubuntu or Debian

sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev libpcre3 libpcre3-dev unzip uuid-dev

Ref: https://www.modpagespeed.com/doc/build_ngx_pagespeed_from_source

Answer (score 0):

Not work here for Centos 7, nginx 1.16.1:

```
[root@aru-251736 nginx-1.16.1]# ./configure --add-module=../ModSecurity-nginx \
--prefix=/usr/share/nginx \
--sbin-path=/usr/sbin/nginx \
--modules-path=/usr/lib64/nginx/modules \
--conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
--error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
--http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log \
--http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/client_body \
--http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/proxy \
--http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/fastcgi \
--http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/uwsgi \
--http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/tmp/scgi \
--pid-path=/run/nginx.pid \
--lock-path=/run/lock/subsys/nginx \
--with-file-aio \
--with-ipv6 \
--with-http_ssl_module \
--with-http_v2_module \
--with-http_realip_module \
--with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-http_addition_module \
--with-http_xslt_module=dynamic \
--with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic \
--with-http_sub_module \
--with-http_dav_module \
--with-http_flv_module \
--with-http_mp4_module \
--with-http_gunzip_module \
--with-http_gzip_static_module \
--with-http_random_index_module \
--with-http_secure_link_module \
--with-http_degradation_module \
--with-http_slice_module \
--with-http_stub_status_module \
--with-http_perl_module=dynamic \
--with-http_auth_request_module \
--with-mail=dynamic \
--with-mail_ssl_module \
--with-pcre --with-pcre-jit \
--with-stream=dynamic \
--with-stream_ssl_module \
--with-google_perftools_module \
--with-debug \
--with-cc-opt='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 grecord-gcc-switches -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 -m64 -mtune=generic'
```

....

```
checking for IP_PKTINFO ... not found
checking for IPV6_RECVPKTINFO ... not found
checking for TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT ... not found
checking for TCP_KEEPIDLE ... not found
checking for TCP_FASTOPEN ... not found
checking for TCP_INFO ... not found
checking for accept4() ... not found
checking for kqueue AIO support ... not found
checking for Linux AIO support ... not found
checking for Linux AIO support (SYS_eventfd) ... not found

./configure: no supported file AIO was found
Currently file AIO is supported on FreeBSD 4.3+ and Linux 2.6.22+ only
```